# Autocorrect anywhere on Windows

Tags: gratis, windows-7, spell-checker

I am looking for a program that runs in any program on Windows that autocorrects common misspellings (like iOS's keyboard).

I would like:

- it to be free
- it to automatically auto-correct (in case that wasn't obvious ;)
- it to be kept up to date (with common misspellings) automatically
- it to run in *any* program (or as many as possible)
- it to run on Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: This seems like a very sophisticated algorithm for correcting mistyped sentences, but I don't know if it's been integrated in any program as an "autocorrect everywhere" thing: https://github.com/wolfgarbe/SymSpellCompound

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (free, open-source, Windows), something along the lines of this [script](https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/AutoHotkeyScripts/blob/master/others/wikipedia_autocorrect.ahk), which automatically auto-correct and should run in most program. ([original source](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/7379-autoreplace/)).

The main idea behind the script is that `::campain::campaign` in AHK will cause any mistyped "campain" to be retyped as "campaign".

Note that Windows 8 [provides](http://dottech.org/89729/windows-8-how-to-turn-off-spell-check-and-autocorrect-on-pc-or-tablet/) a spell check feature throughout the entire system. :

[image]

Comment: looks good. also option to choose some different misspellings. +1

Comment: [The Windows built-in feature doesn't seem to be working for me on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1331854/windows-10-spelling-autocorrect-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

[PhraseExpress](https://www.phraseexpress.com/) is a text expander that has built-in autocorrect. It's free for personal use and is available on Windows, Mac, Android, and iOS.

[image: PhraseExpress AutoCorrect]

Answer (score 0):

Try https://beeftext.org/ , it's simpler than PhraseExpress and real freeware.

If you just need textexpanding and not all the bells and whistles of phraseexpress I recommend beeftext.
It's freeware and mucht simpler to use.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).